# SQL Server Full-text crawl log location

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, log

This might be a silly question, but I can't for the life of me figure out where the crawl logs for my SQL Server 2012 instance are. TechNet says to look under `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG` for 2008, but the `LOG` folder does not exist under `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL`.

I have upwards of 500,000 failed records after my last FTS index population and I need to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to find the full text log location with the following code:

```
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Logging SQL Server messages in file'
```

I don't think it's possible to split them away from the normal SQL Error log as this [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/694037/sql-full-text-catalog-log-file-location) suggests.

Comment: Thank you! That provided the location. IT/DBA seems to have moved the logs folder to the `D:` on that machine.