# How to find root cause for SQL full text crawl error 30059?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2019

Doing several FT index rebuilds after upgrading SQL server and one the FT index crawls died with error 30059 but not much else for root cause.  I can resume the population attempt but would like to know why it failed before retrying.

> 2-02-18 14:51:40.32 spid388s    Error: 30059, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> 2022-02-18 14:51:40.32 spid388s    A fatal error occurred during a full-text population and caused the population to be cancelled. Population type is: FULL; database name is MyDB(id: 28); catalog name is MyCatalog (id: 111); table name MyTable (id: 368903423). Fix the errors that are logged in the full-text crawl log. Then, resume the population. The basic Transact-SQL syntax for this is: ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name RESUME POPULATION.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Full-text crawl log location](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146777/sql-server-full-text-crawl-log-location)

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The SQL error log doesn't appear to have any of the full text errors logged.  Looking at the FT log files only reveals that fatal error 30059 has occurred.  Error 30059 is a mystery so far.